Where should I expect new growth on this Monstera cutting?
After a Thrip invasion on my Monstera I took a cutting of 2 healthy leaves (with nodes) and ensured it was Thrip-free before propagating in water. I left it for a couple of months in regularly refreshed water and a large root system developed, I then I re-potted it as you see in the pictures. It's been in this pot for about 2 months.
I'm a bit confused where/if I should be expecting to see new growth? The cutting included nodes but did not include the newest leaf growth so I don't know where shoots will grow from. Do I need to re-orientate the cutting to better allow for growth? I should say this has been quite stable in the potting mix and seems to like its new home, I've not seen any signs that it's dying. Is it a case of just waiting?



Some cuttings just take time to develop leaves.  Usually the push is on to make roots and when there are enough energy reserves a leaf is the next step.
This plant is capable of fast growth once it is established but for now I think you should consider waiting another two months for signs of a leaf node.
Another option is just buying a new plant as they are commonly available.

Assuming your cuttings were correctly taken and successfully strike, new leaves will appear from out of the soil next to where you planted each leaf. Keep them well watered and with luck they'll take off.
